# How to create a swanky SurfaceSlider

Tags: slider, pixelsense

I am new to surface programming and stumbled upon this [Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/testxfl.jpg/) which I understand is a slider control on a tag visualization (in this case a card). This slider is

- curved as opposed to conventional straight track
- has a bigger thumb which displays the current position (thus eliminating the need of a separate label)
- has a glowing feel (I understand this is due to overlapping controls with different blur radius)

Can anyone help with how to make such control.

-V

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom-built control rather than a standard SurfaceSlider.  It's not build using TagVisualizer either but that's only because the app that this picture shows was built ~2 years prior to TagVisualizer existing.

Now you should certainly use TagVisualizer to streamline an implementation of this but you'll still have to create a custom slider control - SurfaceSlider will not be a good fit because it assumes that the user is moving their finger linearly.

Within your custom arching slider control, you *can* use SurfaceThumb (which SurfaceSlider itself uses) to get the big glowing thumb... then just needs to listen to the Delta events on the thumb and move it along the constrained path as appropriate.